# Does pwntools provide any Radare2 integration?

Tags: debugging, debuggers

I want to use pwntools with Radare2, since this is my debugger of choice.

However, I can only find GDB-related library calls in pwntools' documentation (pwnlib.gdb).

Anyone with experience in integration Radare2 with pwntools?

Answer (score 1):

There is no integrated way to debug using radare2, but there is 2 workarounds :

##### 1. Tell the script to wait for a debbuger

You can use `util.proc.wait_for_debugger` start the process when a debugger is connected.

**Exploit script :**

```
io = process('my_binary')
pid = util.proc.pidof(io)[0]
print("The pid is " + str(pid))
util.proc.wait_for_debugger(pid)
```

**Launch Radare2:**

`r2 -A -d pid`

See here for an example : https://ret2libc.com/article/19/pwntools-radare2-debugger

##### 2. Use pwndbg

Radare2 can be called from `pwndbg`. It's possible to use the gdb integration in pwntools, and the use the command `r2` to switch to radare.

[image]

https://github.com/pwndbg/pwndbg